# how to two versions of one wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, header, multilingual, webmatrix

I am making a wordpress site in webmatrix, and need it to be both in english and french, so far i have created a button in header.php to link individual pages to their counterpart

but what i did not consider is how to call the different headers and footers for every single page (french version and english version) as well as the amount of work will be to customize the button to be unique for every single page

is there a way to automate everything? prehaps two folders to store a copy of the whole site, one with english and the other french? can i get the different headers in each folder and just have the index call on header();?

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this the hard way.

First, WordPress is fairly strong in the language / internationalization area.  You might consider reading up on this: [I18N for WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)

Second, to address your specific question, when you call a header or a footer, you do so using the WordPress function:

[get_header()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)

and

[get_footer()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer)

With both of these functions, you can pass in a parameter that causes WordPress to find and load a different template, like so:

`wp_header('english');`

Will attempt to load the template file titled `header-english.php`

`wp_header('french');` will attempt to load the templat file titled `header-french.php`

So, you could have a variable which told the site which version to load:

`$language = 'english';

get_header($langage);`

There's an excellent write-up on WordPress codex that covers mult-lingual sites:

[Multilingual WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress)

Finally, there are plugins out there that claim to make multi-language WP sites easier.  I do not have any direct experience with them, so cannot vouch for them:

[WPML](http://wpml.org/), [Polylang](http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/), and others.

Comment: wow thank you! i did not know these things existed, will try them out and get back to you!

Comment: for $language='english', how can i set it so that it knows all my english pages are in english and all my french pages are in french?

Answer (score 1):

You have to choose between **WPML** http://wpml.org/ (not free) and **qTranslate** http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/ (free). Both are compatible with the latest WordPress v.3.8.1

Personally I use **WPML**.

Comment: so if i had a french/english tab in the header of every page, would either of these two automate the links to go to the respective translated side for every page?

Comment: If by tabs you mean something like flags (French/English) and reloading the page when clicking the flag... YES!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  http://wpml.org/ this is the most common multi langage plug in, and it does help a lot! in the back office of wordpress pages are linked with their respective tranlastion, you can customize url....etc...
I tried it and it does worth the money to me
I hope it helps

Daco